# Probability that given a 1000 page book with 1000 misprints, a page will have 3 misprints.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

**Setting**

A book of 1000 pages contains 1000 misprints. Estimate the chances that a given page contains at least three misprints.

**Solution**

My solution is

$$\binom{1000}{1}\left(\frac{1}{1000}\right)^3\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^{1000 - 3}$$

Please confirm?

Comment: It should be $1000$ choose $3$.

Comment: So why is that I'm choosing 3 misprints, and not choosing 1 page?

Comment: It's a little unclear (to me) what you're asking for.  Do you want the probability that there will be *some* page with at least three misprints, or do you mean the probability that if you open to a random page, it will have at least three misprints?

Comment: I believe the question is asking for the probability that given a random page, it'll have 3 misprints. So I suppose that if we're fixing a page, then success is a misprint. And there's 1000 choose 3 ways to choose 3 misprints. Hence the $\binom{1000}{3}$? But what would the probability that there will be some page with at least three misprints

Comment: BarryCipra @heropup cleared up my confusion. But thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your expression has a number of problems:  First of all, even if you assume a binomial distribution applies to your situation, your expression only calculates the probability of **exactly** three errors, not **at least** three.

Second, the binomial coefficient is incorrect:  it should be $\binom{1000}{3}$ if you were to apply such a formula.

Third--and this more or less makes the previous two comments irrelevant:  a binomial distribution is not an appropriate model for this problem.  Instead, a Poisson distribution is the intended approach.  This is because if you use a binomial distribution, what is your $n$ and what is your $p$?  $n$ is the number of independent trials, and $p$ is the individual probability of "success" for that trial.  Here, you are sampling only a *single* page out of $1000$ pages, and counting the number of errors in that page.  We cannot choose $n = 1000$ nor can we choose $p = 1/1000$.  Such a choice of parameters would be equivalent to a situation where you were to look at *every* page in the book, in which each page has a probability of $1/1000$ of having an error, and getting the probability that $x$ *pages with errors* are found among those $n$ pages (but you would be counting *pages*, not *errors*, so in particular, such pages may contain more than one error on each!).  That isn't what you want.

Instead, what we want to do is use a Poisson distribution:  here, we have an *error rate* of $1000$ errors per $1000$ pages, or equivalently, $\lambda = 1$ error per page.  Thus, if we look at a single page, the random number of errors found in that page is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda = 1$, and the probability of finding $k$ errors on that page is $$\Pr[X = k] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$  Thus the probability that there are at least $3$ errors is $$\Pr[X \ge 3] = 1 - \Pr[X \le 2] = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = 1 - e^{-1} (1 + 1 + \tfrac{1}{2}).$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad you caught and corrected my fundamental understanding in what the binomial distribution is expressing!

Comment: *misunderstanding

Comment: @ExamPrep & heropup: A binomial distribution *is* appropriate here: for any given, single page, we can regard each misprint as a trial, with the trial succeeding if that misprint happens to fall on the given page. See my answer for more details. (Of course, a Poisson approximation is perfectly fine here, too, but it would break down if the number of pages and misprints was much smaller; say, 2 misprints on 2 pages.)

Comment: Indeed, you are correct; such is a valid interpretation of the question.

Comment: Note that the final result here is not exactly correct; you have $=$ in a few places where you should actually have $\approx$. (To see this, observe that $\Pr[X > 1000] = 0$, whereas your approach would calculate a small positive value for $\Pr[X > 1000]$.) This approximation is fine -- the question says to "estimate" -- but the answer needs to indicate it. The current wording makes it sound like it is an exact answer.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that the misprints are independently distributed across the book, and equally likely to be on any page, the number of misprints $X$ on a given page is [binomially distributed](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n = 1000$ ($=$ number of misprints) and $p = 1/1000$ ($=$ probability of a misprint ending up on the given page).

Thus, the probability of there being at least $k$ misprints on the page can be calculated using the [cumulative distribution function](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) $F_b$ of the binomial distribution:

$$\begin{aligned}
{\rm Pr}(X \ge k)\ 
&= 1 - {\rm Pr}(X \le k-1) \\
&= 1 - F_b(k-1; n, p) \\
&= 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} {n \choose i}\, p^i (1-p)^{n-i}, \\
\end{aligned}$$

and thus:

$$\begin{aligned}
{\rm Pr}(X \ge 3)\ 
&= 1 - F_b(2; 1000, \tfrac1{1000}) \\
&= 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{2} {\textstyle {1000 \choose i}}\, \left(\tfrac{1}{1000}\right)^i \left(\tfrac{999}{1000}\right)^{1000-i}, \\
&= 1
 - \left(\tfrac{999}{1000}\right)^{1000}
 - \left(\tfrac{999}{1000}\right)^{999}
 - \tfrac12 \left(\tfrac{999}{1000}\right)^{999}.
\end{aligned}$$

We can approximate this probability by noting that, for $x \approx 0$, $(1-x)^n \approx e^{-nx}$, and thus:

$$\begin{aligned}
{\rm Pr}(X \ge 3)\ 
&\approx 1 - e^{-1} - e^{-\frac{999}{1000}} - \tfrac12 e^{-\frac{999}{1000}} \\
&\approx 1 - \tfrac52 e^{-1} \approx 0.08.
\end{aligned}$$

Another way to obtain the same approximation is to note that, for large $n$ and small $p$, the binomial distribution is [well approximated](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Poisson_approximation) by the [Poisson distribution](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with rate parameter $\lambda = np$.  The Poisson distribution has the CDF:

$$F_P(k; \lambda) = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{\lambda^i}{i!},$$

and thus we get:

$$\begin{aligned}
{\rm Pr}(X \ge 3)\ 
&= 1 - F_b(2; 1000, \tfrac1{1000}) \\
&\approx 1 - F_P(2; 1) \\
&= 1 - e^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^2 \frac{1}{i!} \\
&= 1 - \tfrac52e^{-1}. \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you, your interpretation is more in line with my original impression, minus the "at least" part that I completely glossed over. And thank you for making the connection to the Poisson exact.

Answer (score 4):

The number of ways 1000 mistakes can happen in 1000 pages is $1000^{1000}$. Assuming all of them are equally likely, we calculate the required probability as follows.

The number of ways given page can have at most 2 mistakes is $999^{1000} + 1000(999)^{999}+\frac{1000*999}{2}999^{998}$.

Therefore the required probability is $$1-\frac{999^{1000} + 1000(999)^{999}+\frac{1000*999}{2}999^{998}}{1000^{1000}}$$

Comment: +1 This answer (decimal expansion 0.080209...) differs slightly from the other answers (decimal expansion 0.080301...). This seems to be correct because it actually uses the fact that there are 1000 mistakes in the book as a hard constraint instead of using that to derive an error rate for a particular page.

Answer (score 3):

The usual model here is a Poisson model: the number $X$ of misprints in a randomly chosen page has roughly Poisson distrobution, mean (and therefore parameter) $\lambda=\frac{1000}{1000}$. We have  $\Pr(X\ge 3)=1-\Pr(X\le 2)$.

And $\Pr(X\le 2)\approx  e^{-1}\frac{1^0}{0!}+e^{-1}\frac{1^1}{1!}+e^{-1}\frac{1^2}{2!}$.